# How do a selectively delete an element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

In nodejs, I have an array that looks somewhat like this.

```
["var/sys/log","var/sys/log/image", "var/sys/.dawn/noon", 
"var/sys/.sbs/rise", "var/sys/.iris/quell", "....." ]
```

The array index is around 50-70

Now I want to delete all the elements that contain a "." expect for the entries that contain .sbs.

Any help here would be great. I have been racking my head off.

Edit after comments

I have tried array.filter, array.splice(foo.indexOf('.'>-1). But it deletes everything including .sbs.

And if it has sbs in it, I shouldn't delete it

Runtime is Nodejs v8 and not a browser.

Comment: What have you tried?  What methods did you think you might use?  We prefer to help you figure out where you've gone wrong AFTER you show us what you've tried rather than just write the code for you from scratch.  Hint, you might find the array method `.filter()` useful.

Comment: note that .filter() is not supported in IE 8

Comment: What happens if a string contains both `.` and `.sbs` (at different places)? E.g. should `"foo.bar.sbs"` be deleted?

Comment: @PaulKienitz - a [polyfill is available on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) if IE8 support is still needed.  There's little need to reinvent the world for this kind of stuff, even for old browsers.

Comment: @PaulKienitz I think the OP wants to execute the JavaScript within the node.js environment, not a browser.

Comment: Updated. I have used filter and indexOf. It deletes everything with a . But I want to save entries that have .sbs

Comment: @Oriol it should be retained

Comment: check `if (item.indexOf('.sbs') !== -1)` first